# Inheriting From The Textbox Control And Creating Your Own

Tags: c#, user-controls, textbox, custom-controls

I am trying to implement my own `Textbox` control which implements built-in validation such as number checking etc, and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article on MSDN.

Now I have created custom controls before and they were always `User Controls` which could be imported into Visual Studio's designer, but the implementation shown on the MSDN doesn't seem to support this.

Can I also import that class into VS's designer, or do I have to do it in another way? I could create a `User Control` and insert a `Textbox` in that, but then it would have that grey area around it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently all you have to do is to inherit from the `TextBox` class and that will create a component, which is different than a `User Control`. This can be inserted into VS' toolbox, which is great. No need for `User Controls` here...

Answer (score -1):

The class `NumericTextBox` fromt the article you mentioned inherits from the class `TextBox`. In that case it can not inherit from the class `UserControl`.

I think that it is the best option to create a `User Control` and insert the `NumericTextBox` in it, as you suggested. If you set the `Dock` property of the button to value `Fill`, there should be no grey area around it. Visually, it should not be possible to recognize that the button is inside a `User Control`.

Comment: What makes no sense? A text box has a Dock property, which you should set to Fill like that: `yourTextBox.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;` to get rid of the grey area. If the user control will be small enough or you set `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink` it will do the thing. Of course, if the component does not have to be `UserControl` (as you claimed for some reasons related to a code you have) you can put that text box to a form directly without wrapping.

Comment: You said I should put the `NumericTextBox` inside the `User Control`, when the whole problem was that I couldn't get the `NumericTextBox` to show in the toolbox. Anyway, it doesn't really matter, it works now, thanks for helping.

Comment: Sorry for that, I probably misunderstood your needs. I thought you need a class which inherits from `UserControl`. I am happy you solve your problem an easy way.